# Raise event from one class to another

Tags: c#, timer, console, stopwatch

So i want to start check time passed from my `class` and when this `time` passed (1 minute) i want to raise event:

```
public class TimeOut
{
    private readonly int TIME_OUT = 60;
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private Stopwatch _stopwatch;
    public event TimeOutHandler TimePassed;

    public void Initiate()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _stopwatch.Start();
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 >= TIME_OUT)
        {
            if (TimePassed!=null)
            {
                TimePassed(sender, null);
                Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _stopwatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
TimeOut timeOut = new TimeOut();
timeOut.TimePassed += timeOut_TimePassed;
timeOut.Initiate();
timeOut.Start();

private void timeOut_TimePassed(object sener, System.EventArgs e)
{

}
```

So i don't know why but it seems that my `timer elapsed` function never start.
i try `_timer.Enabled = true;` instead of `_timer.Start();` but this still now helps.

Comment: `TimePassed(sender, null);` it's better to pass an `EventArgs.Empty` instead of `null`. `TimePassed(sender, EventArgs.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

It hit the function for me, after waiting 1 minute.

But, your code didnt compile from just copying and pasting. Changed the event to a delegate and I had to make your private method static.

Also not sure about the last bit of your question, but in my case at least, the console closes immediately. So I added Console.Read() at the end to wait for the timer to elapse. var x is just for a breakpoint

Hope this helps

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimeOut timeOut = new TimeOut();
            timeOut.TimePassed += timeOut_TimePassed;
            timeOut.Initiate();
            timeOut.Start();

            Console.Read();
        }

        // Changed this
        private static void timeOut_TimePassed(object sener, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var x = 1;
        }
    }

    public class TimeOut
    {
        private readonly int TIME_OUT = 60;
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        private Stopwatch _stopwatch;
        // Changed this
        public delegate void TimeOutHandler(object sener, EventArgs e);
        public event TimeOutHandler TimePassed;

        public void Initiate()
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _stopwatch.Start();
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 >= TIME_OUT)
            {
                if (TimePassed != null)
                {
                    TimePassed(sender, null);
                    Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```